getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND test.localhost on nodejs
I am trying to use subdomains with localhost on nodejs. I'm on mac, and I see that the OS doesn't resolve subdomains by default:
$ dscacheutil -q host -a name localhost     
name: localhost
ipv6_address: ::1

name: localhost
ip_address: 127.0.0.1

$ dscacheutil -q host -a name test.localhost
# not found

reproducable example:
# node terminal 1 as a server
const http = require('http');
http.createServer((request, res) => {
  res.write('Working!');
  res.end();
}).listen(3000);

when I try below, it doesn't work when I'm disconnected from wifi:
// fails: Uncaught AxiosError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND test.localhost
await axios.get("http://test.localhost:3000")

// works:
await axios.get("http://localhost:3000")

I recently changed location and it stopped working even if I'm connected to wifi (no clues why). I worked around the issue with a hacky solution (shared it here)
But I also realized that even without the solution, axios on Chrome is able to send requests to test.localhost without this adapter. This is quite odd, because if I do the same from node, it gets getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND.
So my question is, does anyone have any idea why this difference and how can I fix the nodejs side more elegantly? If not, how does Chrome resolve localhost differently than node?
(PS: I don't want to have a custom step of modifying /etc/hosts for this project to work)
(PS2: I am trying to set this up in a way I can use the same code in both server side and client side, so using a node specific module is not an option)


So my question is, does anyone have any idea why this difference and how can I fix the nodejs side more elegantly? If not, how does Chrome resolve localhost differently than node?

Chrome has a whole internal "name resolution" layer above the OS-provided getaddrinfo, which e.g. performs its own caching, does DoH/DoT, and implements various RFC-recommended special cases. Much like you've made Axios use a custom adapter, Chrome's HTTP client component always uses Chrome's own name resolution component; the same goes for Firefox.
In this case, Chrome implements the IETF I-D let-localhost-be-localhost to guarantee that localhost will always resolve to the loopback address, regardless of what the OS does – e.g. in case the 'localhost' /etc/hosts entry is missing. (Although the I-D did not become an RFC, I recall all of the major browsers wanted this, to improve security for things that interact with 'localhost' APIs.)
